# How to create a window to display RGB kinect camera?

Tags: c++, kinect

I have project to use kinect to detect colors and I am using MS Visual Studio 2010. The kinect installer I am using is Kinect SDK 1.6 and for the color detection part I am using open cv, c++. I know that Kinect SDK can now support c++, but my problem right now is how to create a simple window to display RGB camera, to see what Kinect see. Is there any simple way to create the window??

Answer (score 0):

There are a multitude of examples of how to do this in the Developers Toolkit, as well the [Kinect for Windows Samples on CodePlex](http://kinectforwindows.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple examples of how to do this.

In addition, included in the SDK is open source code examples which you can use to assist in obtain RGB, IR and Depth images!